# Creating a slashdot menu with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slashdot

Im just trying to creating a slashdot menu for my site and this is what I got so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
    $('ul').each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
           $('ul').closest('li').slideToggle(300);
        });
    }); 
});
```

This just doesn't work at all as you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HEC7z/)

My HTML is:

```
<ul>
    Click 1
    <li>1.1</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    Click 2
    <li>2.1</li>
</ul>
```

Hope someone can help me get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need not do `each and the click`. just click loop will take care of both.

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
           $('ul').click(function(){
            $(this).children('li:first').slideToggle(300);
        });
});
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/HEC7z/2/

Comment: note that .closest() begins with the current element and travels up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied selector.  which is why he used first instead

Comment: he used "closest('li')", what i understand from this is he is trying to find out the closest li that is the first li inside the particular ul

Comment: exactly, i was clarifying your answer.  @dku used 'li:first' instead of closest() because closest is similar to parents